# Модели Django. Добавить разделитель между полями

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть модель:

```
class field_model(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Когда мы будем добавлять на сайт объект, соответствующий данной модели, мы увидем три объекта `field`, идущих один за другим в том порядке, как прописано в модели.

```
field_1
field_2
field_3
```

***Вопрос:*** Как разделить строки в модели заголовком, чтобы при добавлении нового объекта пользователь видел следующее отображение:

```
field_1

< Title >
field_2
field_3
```

Где **Title** это некий логический разделитель, для полей, описывающих разные свойства объекта

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

```
class FieldMmodelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('field_1',)}),
        ('Title', {'fields': ('field_2', 'field_2')}),
    )
```

Comment: m0nte-cr1st0, спасибо! Да, это как раз то, что нужно!